# Convert strings to pandas timestamps without date

Tags: python, pandas

How should I convert the time '14:12:2006' , '1200' and '1500' into pandas datetime with just the time part so that I can check if the first time is between the other two.

What I am looking for is:

```
12:00  <  14:12:2006  <  15:00
```

I just need the conversion, not the comparison.

Comment: what is 2006 in the 2nd ?

Comment: Its seconds but a higher resolution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only need to compare the them , you can do with

```
s=pd.Series(['14:12:2006' , '1200' , '1500']).str.replace(':','').astype(str)
s=s.str.ljust(s.str.len().max(),'0').astype(int)
s.iloc[1]<s.iloc[0]<s.iloc[2]
True
```

---

```
s
0    14122006
1    12000000
2    15000000
dtype: int64
```

Comment: Can I not do so without converting them to integers? In timestamps or deltatimes? @WeNYoBen

Comment: @NeeravKaushal it is most easy way base on my knowledge